# trigger click on hidden (using css) vaadin button with javascript

Tags: vaadin7

Page has button with custom style

> (display:none)

, and  a label with contentmode html which writes anchor tag  with onclick javascript to find the button mentioned above with its id and click trigger, here  is my code

```
final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    Button  buttonHideen= new Button();
    buttonHideen.setId("hiddenButtonElementId");
    buttonHideen.addStyleName("hide-component");
    buttonHideen.addClickListener(e-> {
        com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert('hidden button clicked')");
    });
    layout.addComponent(buttonHideen);
    String aHtml=" <a href='#' onclick=$('#hiddenButtonElementId').trigger('click')>Click proxy link</a>  ";
    Label  test=new Label(aHtml,com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode.HTML);
    layout.addComponent(test);
    setContent(layout);
```

my aim is to trigger click on vaadin button  using javascript, on clicking the link    javascript executes but no call is sent to server.

I tried looking at the generated html , vaadin creates div for button and places ID attribute on this div, this div contins a span tag with the text in button constructor, clicking on this span tag sent request to server.

here the generated html

```
    <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="v-button v-widget" id="hiddenButtonElementId"><span class="v-button-wrap"><span class="v-button-caption">test button</span></span></div>

$(#'hiddenButtonElementId').find('.v-button-caption').trigger('click')
```

this worked for me

Comment: Any particular reason why you could not use a _clickable label addon/extension_, such as [LabelButon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/labelbutton) or [ClickableLabelExtension](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/clicklabelextension)?

Comment: no its just that we already have plain html menu using bootstrap. Your comment helps thank you.